# Night of the Owls story arcs?

Tags: dc, batman, suggested-order, the-new-52

Hi just I'm new to comic and I want to  ask how to follow the release  story arcs because I start with Batman: Night of the Owls I have bought the batman vol 1 court of owls,batman vol 2 city of owls and Night of the Owls. just want to ask what is the order I have to read

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I read them, you should go like this:

- **Batman Vol. 1 - The Court of Owls**
- **Batman Vol. 2 - City of Owls**
- **Batman - Night of the Owls**

[image]

The reason being is the three-part backup story "*Fall of the House of Wayne*" collected in the **Night of the Owls** book which, kind of, spoils key plot points regarding both the Pennyworths and the Waynes if read prior to **City of Owls**.

You may also want to read **Nightwing Vol. 2 - Night of Owls** which collects **Nightwing #0** and **#8-12**.

The **Batman - Night of the Owls** book only collects issues **8** & **9** of **Nightwing**.  But that is up to you of course.  Oh, and **Justice League #8** has a brief appearance of the Talons in it.